# ResourcesNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID" on code

```
private void getOTPFromMessage(String message) { Pattern otpPatter = Pattern.compile("(|^)\d{6}");

Matcher matcher = otpPatter.matcher(message);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String otp = matcher.group().toString();

    System.out.println("otp = " + otp);
    System.out.println("otp.length() = " + otp.length());

    etInputOTP1.setText(otp.charAt(0));//this line 
    etInputOTP2.setText(otp.charAt(1));
    etInputOTP3.setText(otp.charAt(2));
    etInputOTP4.setText(otp.charAt(3));
    etInputOTP5.setText(otp.charAt(6));
    etInputOTP6.setText(otp.charAt(5));

}

}
```

After getting the error application is getting crashed.

can anyone explain me this exception and how to resolve it.

exception trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vedantkakade.liveasytask, PID: 21106
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.vedantkakade.liveasytask/com.vedantkakade.liveasytask.VerifyOTP}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x30
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5138)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x30
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:382)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6953)
        at com.vedantkakade.liveasytask.VerifyOTP.getOTPFromMessage(VerifyOTP.java:94)
        at com.vedantkakade.liveasytask.VerifyOTP.onActivityResult(VerifyOTP.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5138) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you invoke `setText('char')`, your'e actually calling the setText function that expects a string `resource` id, thats why your'e getting a resource not found exception.

Try to concat it to an empty string

```
.setText(otp.charAt(0) + "");
```

or

```
.setText(String.valueOf(otp.charAt(0)));
```